# SyntaxError in Offices#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tried accessing offices.json from my database on a RoR app but got this weird error. Can't seem to find anything online that tells me what's going on. Any suggestions? Seems like this error affects a couple of models, while for some reason others work fine when I tried to load the json file through the browser.

```
Showing /home/terence/Dropbox/ruby/rails_projects/techdata/app/views/offices/index.json.jbuilder where line #3 raised:
        /home/terence/Dropbox/ruby/rails_projects/techdata/app/views/offices/index.json.jbuilder:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
          json.url office_url(office, format: :json)

      Extracted source (around line #3):

      1 json.array!(@offices) do |office|
      2 json.extract! office, 
      3 json.url office_url(office, format: :json)
      4 end
```

Office.rb:

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Full trace:

```
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:299:in `module_eval'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:299:in `compile'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:248:in `block in compile!'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:236:in `synchronize'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:236:in `compile!'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:142:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/terence/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/render_overrides.rb:14:in `render_with_remotipart'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__1626081210788053227__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack-pjax (0.7.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2204569670449087570__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/terence/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/terence/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/terence/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: It's as though you should include the code that causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like I've figured it out. Somehow when I executed a migration for my office model, the index.json.jbuilder failed to update itself with the added column. Not sure why this is so, but modify index.json.jbuilder worked out:

Before:

```
json.array!(@offices) do |office|
  json.extract! office,
  json.url office_url(office, format: :json)
end
```

After:

```
json.array!(@offices) do |office|
  json.extract! office, :headquarters
  json.url office_url(office, format: :json)
end
```